# performance issue with @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle11g

I have performance problem with @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. Fetching a list (425 rows) from DB via Hibernate3/Spring2.5 is taken about 12 sec. It is too long. I don't understand why.

Umsuser Taetigkeit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UMSUSER_TAETIGKEIT")
public class UmsuserTaetigkeit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@GenericGenerator(name = "taetigkeit_generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "taetigkeit"))
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="taetigkeit_generator")
@Column(name="TAETIGKEIT_ID")
private long taetigkeitId;

@Column(name="EDITOR_USER_ID")
private String editorUserId;

//TODO: check date/time format
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="TASK_TIMESTAMP")
private Date taskTimestamp;

@Column(name="UMS_CONFIGURATION")
private BigDecimal umsConfiguration;

@Column(name="UMS_ROLE")
private String umsRole;

@Column(name="UMS_WERK")
private String umsWerk;

@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Taetigkeit taetigkeit;

    //getter and setter
public static String fetchJoin() {
    return " left join fetch o.taetigkeit ";
}
    }
```

Taetigkeit:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TAETIGKEIT")
    public class Taetigkeit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@GenericGenerator(name = "taetigkeit_generator", strategy = "sequence-identity", parameters = @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "TAETIGKEIT_SEQ"))
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="taetigkeit_generator")
@Column(name="TAETIGKEIT_ID")
private long taetigkeitId;

@Column(name="PUBLISH_STATE")
private String publishState = "N";

@Lob
@Column(name="TAETIGKEIT_XML")
private String taetigkeitXml = "";

    //setter and getter
    }
```

Methods findAll:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
   public List<T> findAll(final String fetchJoin,final String... orderby) {

    final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer(
            "SELECT "+ INSTANCE +" from ");
    queryString.append(type.getSimpleName()).append(INSTANCE_SPACE);
    if(fetchJoin != null) {
        queryString.append(fetchJoin);
    }
    if(orderby.length > 0) {
        queryString.append(" order by ");
        boolean addComma = false;
        for(String arg : orderby) {
            arg = INSTANCE + "." + arg;
            if(addComma) {
                queryString.append(",");
            } else {
                addComma = true;
            }
            queryString.append(arg);
        }
    }

    final Query query = this.em.createQuery(queryString.toString());

    return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
}
```

JUnit test methods:

```
    @Test
public void testFinAll_GOOD_CASE() {
    List<UmsuserTaetigkeit> findAll = umsuserTaetigkeitDao.findAll(UmsuserTaetigkeit.fetchJoin());
    assertNotNull(findAll);
    System.out.println(findAll.size());
}
```

SQL Statement:

```
Hibernate: select umsusertae0_.TAETIGKEIT_ID as TAETIGKEIT1_3_0_, taetigkeit1_.TAETIGKEIT_ID as TAETIGKEIT1_6_1_, umsusertae0_.EDITOR_USER_ID as EDITOR2_3_0_, umsusertae0_.TASK_TIMESTAMP as TASK3_3_0_, umsusertae0_.UMS_CONFIGURATION as UMS4_3_0_, umsusertae0_.UMS_ROLE as UMS5_3_0_, umsusertae0_.UMS_WERK as UMS6_3_0_, taetigkeit1_.PUBLISH_STATE as PUBLISH2_6_1_, taetigkeit1_.TAETIGKEIT_XML as TAETIGKEIT3_6_1_ from UMSUSER_TAETIGKEIT umsusertae0_ left outer join TAETIGKEIT taetigkeit1_ on umsusertae0_.TAETIGKEIT_ID=taetigkeit1_.TAETIGKEIT_ID
```

**UPDATE:**

Execution plan

```
    PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Plan hash value: 3626287948                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| Id  | Operation          | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                    |   425 | 54400 |    15   (7)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER   |                    |   425 | 54400 |    15   (7)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| UMSUSER_TAETIGKEIT |   425 | 15725 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAETIGKEIT         |   644 | 58604 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - access("UMSUSERTAE0_"."TAETIGKEIT_ID"="TAETIGKEIT1_"."TAETIGKEIT_ID"(+))                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

15 rows selected
```

Comment: Get the sql execution plan for the statement in question.

Comment: @steve here: select o from UmsuserTaetigkeit o left join fetch o.taetigkeit

Comment: this is no execution plan

Comment: sorry. it is first time for me to use execution plan. see above.